# The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once Exception

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to retrieve a specific number of data for paging, I have no idea why the Skip Query returns an empty List and it throws the following exception "The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once"

```
IEnumerable<ImgOrgSet> query = _ImgOrgRepository.GetImgOrgList();
IEnumerable<ImgOrgSet> queryPaginated = query.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
```

[image: Debuging details]

Comment: possible duplicate of [The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723555/the-result-of-a-query-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above in comments and the signposted duplicate you need to add `.ToList()` to make the results explicitly available for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it throws the exception because you expanded the 'query' variable before in the 'debug window'. Try running it again and don't expand the query/debug.

Comment: I don't think so, I expanded it right after the exception was thrown. I tried running it again without breakpoints and I got a null list. same problem.

Comment: OK. Can you explain why you call GetImgOrgList with size/position arguments, then in second row you try to do it again with Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize)

Comment: No, I only forgot to remove the arguments sorry (edited*), in the first row I retrieve all ImgOrg elements in DB, in the second row I try to get PageSize elements from the CurrentPage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723555/the-result-of-a-query-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once suggests to add .ToList() to 'materialize' the query