# The query results cannot be enumerated more than once in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

this code:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    IEnumerable<view_subject> results = db.ExecuteQuery<view_subject>(query);

    if (dataBind)
    {
        GridViewSearchResults.DataSource = results;
        GridViewSearchResults.DataBind();
    }

    return results.Count();
}
```

Throws me an exception: The query results cannot be enumerated more than once. And I dont understand why? Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Did you look for duplicate questions before asking? Look down the "related" questions at the side of this...

Comment: there is similar question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723555/the-result-of-a-query-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once

Answer (score 1):

Using ToList() will retrieve all records from DB, and now it works on data instead of database query.

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    List<view_subject> results = db.ExecuteQuery<view_subject>(query).ToList();

    if (dataBind)
    {
        GridViewSearchResults.DataSource = results;
        GridViewSearchResults.DataBind();
    }

    return results.Count();
}
```

Comment: An explanation of what you did any why it solves the problem would be helpful here.

Comment: @AndrewBarber you beat me :) .  I added explanation as well.