# Linq to SQL method defaults to ISingleResult

Tags: c#, linq

I have a stored procedure that returns all the columns from a table (InstitutionEntityIP) that maps to the DBML object of the same name. It will return n number of records. However, the codebehind defaults to ISingleResult. 
I would like to have it return an IEnumerable.

I'm getting an error message 'The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.'

My code looks like this:

```
//ContentRepository.cs
private readonly IGIGlobalDataContext db;
// ....
public IEnumerable<InstitutionEntityIP> GetInstitutionEntityIPs(long fromIp, long toIp)
{
    return 
        from ip in db.InstitutionEntityIPs
        where
        (
            (fromIp >= ip.FromIPInteger && fromIp <= ip.ToIPInteger) || //From IP Address parameter is the same or encompassed
            (toIp >= ip.FromIPInteger && toIp <= ip.ToIPInteger) || //To IP Address parameter is the same or encompassed
            (fromIp <= ip.FromIPInteger && toIp >= ip.FromIPInteger) || //Any From IPs in the DB between the parameters 
            (fromIp <= ip.ToIPInteger && toIp >= ip.ToIPInteger) //Any To IPs in the DB between the parameters 
        ) &&
        ip.IsActive &&
        ip.InstitutionEntity.IsActive &&
        Convert.ToDateTime((ip.InstitutionEntity.ExpirationDate ?? (DateTime?)DateTime.Now)) >= DateTime.Now &&
        ip.InstitutionEntity.Institution.IsActive &&
        Convert.ToDateTime((ip.InstitutionEntity.Institution.ExpirationDate ?? (DateTime?)DateTime.Now)) >= DateTime.Now
        select ip;
}
public IEnumerable<InstitutionEntityIP> GetInstitutionEntityIPs(string fromIp, string toIp)
{
    // SearchForConflictingIPs is the method name created when I drop my 
    // stored procedure (also called SearchForConflictingIPs) on the DBML layout
    var ips = db.SearchForConflictingIPs(fromIp, toIp); // returns ISingleResult<InstitutionEntityIP>
    // VVVVVVVVV
    return ips.ToList(); // <-- Needed to specify the .ToList() here <--
    // ^^^^^^^^^
}

// I actually call the method from another class
public static IEnumerable<IGIGlobal_DAL.InstitutionEntityIP> ConflictingIPs(string start, string end)
{
    var cr = new ContentRepository();
    return cr.GetInstitutionEntityIPs(start, end);
}

public RangeValidationResult Validate(bool isUpdate = false, int institutionEntityIPID = 0)
{
    var conflicts = ConflictingIPs(Start.ToString(), End.ToString());

    if (conflicts.Any()) // <---- 'The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.'
    {
        var conflictingEntities = string.Join(", ", conflicts.Select(c => c.InstitutionEntity.InstitutionEntity1).Distinct());
    }
}
```

If you need any more information from me please comment.

Comment: Where does `SearchForConflictingIPs` come from? What do you mean by the bit you've labelled "actual call"? It's very unclear what's going on at the moment...

Comment: Updated with some comments and some missing pieces. Sorry I hadn't included them.

Comment: Found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723555/the-result-of-a-query-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once

Comment: You still haven't shown the declaration of `SearchForConflictingIPs` or explained what created it...

Comment: @JonSkeet he specified this in comments inside method GetInstitutionEntityIPs that SearchForConflictingIPs is generated from storedProcedure in DBML file.

Comment: @vendettamit: Ah, I hadn't seen that part of the edit. It would have been much clearer if that had just been text in the question rather than in comments...

Answer (score 1):

I needed to specify the .ToList() in the public IEnumerable GetInstitutionEntityIPs(string fromIp, string toIp) method.

Found the info I needed here:
[The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723555/the-result-of-a-query-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once)

Answer (score 0):

The function generated by stored procedures in DBML file would return `ISingleResult` and it behaves like a `DataReader`. You are only allowed to get the enumerator to loop through only one time.

In your case:

```
 if (conflicts.Any()) // <---- 'The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.'
```

Means the enumerator has already been used. Here `Any()` also tries to get the enumerator to perform check if there's at least 1 record exists.

So you need to convert the every `ISingleResult` to a list using that enumerator, if you have requirement to loop through multiple times over the collection. So you have to live with `ToList()` in that case.