# How to pass Stored Procedure with DateTime parameter in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime, stored-procedures

```
public List<Data> GetData(string Date1, string Date2, string param3)
{
    var myData= new List<FindData_Result>();
    using (var context = new Config())
    {
        var queryResult = context.FindData(startDate, endDate, param3);
        final= (from a in queryResult select a).ToList();
    }
}
```

How do I pass date1 and end date2 as datetime parameter to my stored procedure?

I am using MVC web api with entity framework (DB first approach)

Comment: if your values are valid for `DateTime`, then just make the parameters `DateTime Date1, DateTime Date2` (but I assume you mean `startDate` and `endDate`, not `Date1` and `Date2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the string representations of your dates, start date and end date, to their DateTime equivalent. This can be done by using the `Parse` method of `DateTime` type, like below:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Parse(Date1);
var endDate = DateTime.Parse(Date2);
var queryResult = context.FindData(startDate, endDate, param3).ToList();
```

You could also use the `ParseExact` method, provided that your string have a specific format. For further info please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: tried this and getting message "The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once"

Comment: var queryResult = context.FindData(startDate, endDate, param3); in this line

Comment: @HDev007 call `ToList` at the end and it will be fixed. Doing so you don't need any more the variable called `final`.

Comment: I read about the error message you mentined and I found this helpful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723555/the-result-of-a-query-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-once. Pay attention on the last comment made  by Ageis, below the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks Christos for help :-)