# The Result of a Query Cannot be Enumerated More than Once (C#) (Entity Framework) (Stored Procedure)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

When I get to `db.GetLabelComponentsByLabelID(LabelIDs.ElementAt(i).Value.ToString()).ToList()`

I get the following exception: `The Result of a Query Cannot be Enumerated More than Once`

I tried to change LabelComponents by calling `ToList()` like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5723643/6173191) suggested.

```
long? GroupID = db.GetGroupIDByName("PrintTest").SingleOrDefault();
ObjectResult<long?> LabelIDs = db.GetLabelIDSFromGroupingsByGroupID(GroupID.ToString());
for (int i = 0; i < LabelIDs.Count(); i++)
{
    var LabelComponents = db.GetLabelComponentsByLabelID(LabelIDs.ElementAt(i).Value.ToString()).ToList();
    List<Component> Label = new List<Component>();

    for(int j = 0; j < LabelComponents.Count(); j++)
    {
        ....
        ....
```

Comment: The code in the first sentence doesn't match your code snippet, are you sure you have `ToList` in your actual code?

Comment: @DavidG  var LabelComponents = db.GetLabelComponentsByLabelID(LabelIDs.ElementAt(i).Value.ToString()).ToList(); It is there. No?

Comment: Put the `.ToList()` after `GetLabelIDSFromGroupingsByGroupID()`

Comment: You need `ToList` on the *first* db call, you are enumerating the `LabelIDs` value multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `ToList` on the *first* db call because you are enumerating the `LabelIDs` value multiple times. `LabelIDs.Count` runs the query the first time, then `LabelIDs.ElementAt` runs it again later on.